# Angular js authentication on app load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I'am fairly new to the angular 1.6.X, and i've some doubts regarding the way authentications runs on angular.

There are two controllers, login and dashboard.
And i am using $transitions.onStart event to validate login when transition from one controller to another.

But what the problem is when i enter the dashboard url directly, it doesn't consider as a transition.

I've tried $rootScope.$on, but it isn't even capture the event.

Can someone tells me what i did wrong?

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $transitions) {
$transitions.onStart({}, function(trans) {
// Auth logic
}),
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
// Auth logic
});
});
```

Comment: [As of version 1.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=class%20autocomplete&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) - "NOTE: State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks as of version 1.0" `$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart"...` won't work for you.

Comment: @OmriLuzon Thanks, i didn't know that, but what event triggers when i enter rouote Url directly on the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure because I used an entierly different solution for this. but did you try **`$transitions.onStart({ to: '*', from: '*' }, function...`** ?

Comment: @OmriLuzon Using from : '**' on transition works, it captures the event when i enter the url. Thanks. Could you please tell me what solution you are using to handle this scenario, that would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't mention it, because I used 3rd party solutions for authentication in my projects (Auth0 and Keycloak), I haven't dealt with it directly at all.